# お願いをする あの子たち relative clause meaning

Tags: meaning, relative-clauses

I posted a [question](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/61353/nuance-of-%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84%E3%82%88%E3%81%86%E3%81%AB%E3%81%97%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84%E3%81%A8-and-a-potential-relative-clause) some time ago about this same sentence, but about a different grammar problem than this one.

So the sentence:

> せめてお願いをするあの子たち以外にはできるだけ迷惑をかけないようにしないと

The context is that the person saying this (monologing) is aiming to later likely fight "those girls", because they'll likely oppose what she feels she needs to do. Mostly because her plan could endanger people.

So here she is saying she'll try to limit bothering others (other than "those girls") to a minimum.

But I'm wondering about the お願いをする あの子たち bit. Is this something like
あの子たち**に**お願いをする so she is also saying she'll first ask them for help/to let her?

Or is this something more nuanced?

I'm mostly wondering because I know what happens afterwards, and she never really does the asking. Well at least not until the plan goes sideways.

So, what's your oppinion on the meaning of お願いをする あの子たち?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

お願いをするあの子たち by itself can mean both:

1. those girls who (will) ask a favor (of someone else)
2. those girls I (will) ask a favor of

Judging from the context you provided, I think it probably means the latter, i.e., this person is going to ask a favor of those girls. But I don't know what this お願い actually refers to.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is important that there is the line break and possible comma after お願いをする according to the other question. I don't think the first part is relative clause at all, since it's probably casually spoken language [the grammar is a bit lax](http://www.guidetojapanese.org/casual.html#part3).

I would interpret it as making a wish (as in to a deity) (せめてお願いをする) and then saying that she has to try to not harm/inconvenience anyone but the girls (あの子たち以外にはできるだけ迷惑をかけないようにしないと)

Comment: Well, this is the original: https://imgur.com/MMCQwmT
It would be a bit strange to typeset this like this if it's as you say. 
But how would you render that first bit then!?